# Getting error as "Class not Registered" in Delphi while using a c# dll

Tags: c#, delphi, dll, com, regasm

I am trying to create a C# DLL which could be used in Delphi. But I am getting an error at implementation:

[image]

My C# code is follows:

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
using System.Text;

namespace WebServiceHelper
{
    [Guid("4762FAC0-9CCC-4F9B-B1CD-E8C15FF13A02")]
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public interface IDataSync
    {
        int Add(int a, int b);
    }

    [Guid("DE887257-1A62-420C-BEED-BC6A73DF8F9D")]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public class DataSync : IDataSync
    {

        public int Add(int a, int b)
        {
            return a + b;
        }
    }
}
```

I have also checked the Registry for COM interop option in C# project:

[image]

Post build, I registered the DLL using `regasm`:

```
regasm.exe D:\path\WebServiceHelper.dll /tlb: "WebServiceHelper.tlb" /codebase
```

In Import Type Library, the `.tlb` or `.dll` file is not visible, so I added it from the Add option:

[image]

Delphi Code:

```pascal
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Label1: TLabel;
    Button1: TButton;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Edit2: TEdit;
    Edit3: TEdit;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

uses WebServiceHelper_TLB;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var helper1 : TDataSync;
begin
  helper1:= TDataSync.Create(Self);
  writeln(helper1.Add(5,5));
  Edit3.Text := InttoStr(helper1.Add(5,5));
end;

end.
```

Comment: Clearly the class wasn't registered. Perhaps the C# is 64 bit and the Delphi is 32 bit, or vice versa.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, i will check this once.
But I have registered the DLL using regasm as follows:
regasm.exe D:\path\WebServiceHelper.dll /tlb: "WebServiceHelper.tlb" /codebase

Comment: Yes, I know that, hence my comment